# ExpressJS same routes being hit multiple times simultaneously

Tags: node.js, express

I'm calling the same route URL multiple times in node ExpressJS at the same time then the value of one request is overriding another request.

Like:

```
api/getdata/12
api/getdata/15
```

Here the data of `ID` 12 is coming inside in request `ID` 15 ,

The first request has a loop like this:

```
var result= [];
if(activityResult && activityResult.status!="error"){

   for (activity of activityResult) {
    var dataList = await somefunction(activity);
    result.push(dataList);

  }
}
```

Comment: Hey.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  In order to get a quality answer, it would help if you included not only the code that you're using to invoke your backend, but the middlewares in your backend that are being invoked.  Also, the precise behavior you're observing and expecting would be nice to have as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `await`, it's not doing what you think. You'll need something a little fancier. Try this:

```
const results = async () => {
  if ( activityResult && activityResult.status !== "error" ) {
    return Promise.all(
      activityResult.map( activity =>
        return new Promise( async ( resolve, reject ) => {
          try { 
            const resolvedActivity = await someFunction( activity )
            resolve( resolvedActivity )
          } catch ( error ) {
            reject( error )
          }
        })
      )
    )
  }
  return []
}
```

This way you'll have all of your results in one array. The `Promise.all` will also make all the requests happen 'at once'.

I haven't tested this code, but it should be what you're looking for.